# Select ActionView::FormHelper html_options not being set

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have the following in my application and I am simply trying to apply a class to the `select` as shown below

```
 <%= f.select :widget_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@widgets, "id", "name"),  html_options: {class: 'form-control'} %>
```

According to the [select helper on API dock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select) it shows it should be set up as followed:

```
select(object, method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {}) public
```

My problem is that for some reason when I inspect the element I see:

```
<select id="user_widget_id" name="user[widget_id]">
```

I don't understand why the class is not being included.

Comment: `<%= f.select 'widget', :widget_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@widgets, "id", "name"),  html_options: {class: 'form-control'} %> ` it will give you like `<select name="widget[widget_id]">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= f.select :widget_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@widgets, "id", "name"), {}, {class: 'form-control'} %>
```

The third parameters is for `options`, you want to pass your `html_options` in the 4th parameters, and no need to actually declare "html_options" too. Hope it helps !

Official doc: `select(object, method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})`

Comment: I did try your above solution before but I think what I was doing was not including the `options` as an empty hash. But thanks

Comment: Yes it definitely is why it wasn't working. It happened a LOT to me when I first started using those helper methods too !